# Word for something timeless, established, or a staple that is spiked with some fashionable thing. For example, a Minecraft Lego set

Tags: single-word-requests

I remember (I think) that there is a word to express the nature of these things, like the Minecraft Lego set, or in more general: something that is somewhat timeless, established, considered kind of a staple, that is spiked with some fashionable thing. I just cannot seem to recall.

In my searching, ChatGPT offered 'fashionable' and 'trendy', but the word I am looking for has a negative ring to it; these examples do not sound that negative to my ears.

Especially in this context the negative connotation comes from the expectation that attaching the current fad to an established thing presumably will make it sell better (aka somewhat of a "quick buck" situation). The Minecraft Lego set might sell better at the moment, but the next generation might not find it that desirable, while a basic lego set most likely will avoid this fate, since it is less anchored to a specific time.

Google offers alternatives like 'in fashion', 'in vogue', 'popular' which yet again, do not have that condemning tone I am looking for.

(The example with Minecraft and Lego reflects my perception, I try to illustrate my point with it in case you are a fan. :D)

Comment: Note: Personally, I will  not answer questions containing stuff from ChatGPT. "spiked with some fashionable thing"? spiked?

Comment: rebranded, rebranding

Comment: @Lambie idk, I had this expression in my head: spiked with sg, in the meaning of something (bad) addeed or mixed into sg. But that might be just my imagination :D Maybe i ask ChatGPT about it :D

Comment: In general, we aren't too keen on overly lacing one's comments with a lot of SMS-type stuff.

Comment: @Lambie don't do it then.

Comment: No, you're supposed to not do it. I am informing you. I already know it.

Comment: Idiomatically I’d use *larded up with* before *spiked* but both basically culinary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Trend-hopping** or **trend-jacking** (also written with a space instead of a hyphen or sometimes as one word) are commonly used for the actions of people and companies that jump onto the latest trend. Such people are **trend-hoppers** or **trend-jackers*.

*Trend-hopping* is often used of individuals who always buy what's trendy at the current time, sometimes with no purpose other than to be thought cool or fashionable, but sometimes for more nefarious purposes, as well as for artists, musicians, etc, who try and follow the latest trend rather than making their own personal music/art. *Trend-jacking* (by analogy with hijacking - especially in the metaphorical [sense 2 a](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hijack) "to take or take control of (something) as if by hijacking") is commonly used of companies who're trying to exploit trends, and has more connotations of seeking money.

Neither term seems to have quite made it to dictionaries, but you can find discussions and examples in writings on marketing, business, etc.

Examples (my emphasis):

- "**Trendjacking**, also known as newsjacking, refers to the practice of capitalizing on a popular trend, news event, or cultural moment to promote one’s own brand, product, or message." [Trendjacking or Hopping on Trends: Good or Bad in the Long Run?](https://www.ereleases.com/pr-fuel/hopping-trends-good-bad-long-run/), E-Releases.
- "There is a great difference between **trend hoppers** and remixers. Although similar, there is a fundamental difference. One siphons cash from a culturally prominent trend, the other pushes it into new territory, bringing it closer to the next big thing." [Trend Hoppers](https://medium.com/@beanorich/trend-hoppers-a165154a2d8a), Rich Beano, Medium, Jun 6, 2020.
- [Trend Hopper](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Trend%20Hopper), Urban Dictionary.
- "Viral fame through **trend-hopping** is a temptation for just about every brand, but it comes with risks." [Timing, tone, and audience: 3 pillars for brands leveraging trends on social](https://www.thedrum.com/opinion/2023/09/29/timing-tone-and-audience-3-pillars-brands-leveraging-trends-social), Ewan Miles, The Drum, Sept 29, 2023
- "**Trend jacking** is a strategic marketing approach employed by numerous leading reputation management firms that helps to boost a website’s visibility online." [Trend Jacking](https://www.fatrank.com/trend-jacking/), James Dooley, Fat Rank.

Comment: True story: I was once told by a world famous record producer that if the song I'm recording now sounds like a popular one from the charts, I'm three months out of date already. The very same producer later trend-jacked me by copying what I was doing in the studio one day, applying the same thing to a band he was working with in the other studio in the building - then released it first & got the #1. Ours then sounded like we were copying & did nothing.

Comment: Nice answer, useful, but I think *trend riding* may be closer.

Comment: I really like these expressions, they definately count as words to me :) Trend riding as well! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

How about **[ephemeral](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/ephemeral)**

> lasting for only a short time:
> *Fame in the world of rock and pop is largely ephemeral.*

Cambridge proposes other options for [continuing for less time than usual](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/thesaurus/articles/continuing-for-less-time-than-usual), including [transient](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/thesaurus/transient) or [transitory](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/thesaurus/transitory), but my first thought was ephemeral & I still prefer it - it carries an implied weakness, vulnerability or even just fad.

Comment: I definately glossed over this word, because it sounded very positive(I am not native), but now that i am looking into the examples it might be it! Thanks!